# The amount I store in Formic does not return to me

Tags: reactjs, formik

[image]

The amount I store in Formic does not return to me.

The value found by the filter is logged in line 57, and in line 58 the same value is placed in Formic.  But when I log the formic value in the next line, sometimes the same value that was taken in line 57 is logged, and sometimes the previous formic value is also logged.  Where is my problem?  please guide me

Comment: I'm pretty sure `setFieldValue` is async, like setting state in React. You can't `console.log` it on the next line and see the change. Just print `formik.values` in the main body of the component so it prints each render, and make sure on the **re-render** it has the new value

Answer (score 0):

Setting states in React is asynchronous. So, there is no guarantee that formic state will be changed before the 2nd console.log. You should use results[0] to do any kind of work in useEffect in this case. But if you really want to change the formic state before the 2nd console log, you can use flushSync .

```
flushSync(()=>{formic......})
console.log()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying
This solved my problem but gave me a warning ( Warning: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. React cannot flush when React is already rendering. ) Is there a way to solve this error or is there another solution

Comment: Since you are using results[0] for setting the formic state, you can use results[0] to console.log() also. React will re-render when useEffect call is finished if there are state changes. Or you can move the code inside useEffect to event handlers since formic values are changing because of an event(user click/ keyboard click).